# Redirect To Domain Before SSL Is Read

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpd

I had to switch servers and I want to redirect all SSL urls to the non-ssl site. The problem I am running into is the https site still throws invalid certificate error even through apache has the redirect implemented.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/sites/www.example.com/main/
    RewriteEngine on
    Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/ssl/www.examplecom/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/www.example.com/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is, how can I do a redirect and avoid the invalid ssl certifcation error in the browser?

Comment: The root domain is still the same  example.com - when you say a different server do you mean a different physical box (and different URL) example.com -> newexample.com

Comment: Domain domain, different physical box. Basically I want to get rid of all ssl

Comment: Are you actually using `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` and `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` in your vhost or have you changed those names for this question?

Answer (score 2):

A proper SSL certificate (containing all required DNS names, and issued by a CA which is directly or indirectly trusted by clients' browsers) and the corresponding private key is required to get a secure connection without browser warnings. The fact that you are just redirecting to a non-SSL site does not matter — the browser must verify that it connected to the correct server before even sending the HTTP request.

If you had a valid certificate previously, but lost the private key during the server migration, you will need to contact the CA to revoke the old certificate and reissue a new certificate for the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The SSL certificate validation happens in the vicinity of the session layer. The HTTP conversation happens at the application layer.

I would suggest that you get a free SSL certificate that matches the host name, if your business type qualifies for that type of certificate. There are many CAs that offer free certificates.